# `WSASend` never triggers completion routine if there was no preceding `WSARead`

Tags: windows, c++11, winsock2, io-completion-ports

I'm developing server-client application which manages req/res topics and does fan-out of some messages. Messages sends out with `WSASend` in overlapped mode with provided Completion routine. Noticed that very next send with `WSASend` after `WSARead` triggers sender's completion routine. While the sends originated in the server w/o preceding `WSARead` doesn't trigger completion routine. Why does that happen?

```
bool CCommunicationServer::ManageReadMessage(UCHAR index)
{
    OVERLAPPED_EX *over = m_readov[index];
    DWORD bytes = 0, flags = 0;

    if (WSARecv(over->socket, &(over->wsabuf), 1, &bytes, &flags, over, &CCommunicationServer::WorkerReadRoutine) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        bytes = WSAGetLastError();

        if (bytes != WSA_IO_PENDING) {
            LOG(ERROR) << std::endl << "WSARecv() failed w/err " << bytes;
            shutdown(m_readov[index]->socket, SD_BOTH);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

bool CCommunicationServer::ManageSendMessage(UCHAR index, char* msg, OVERLAPPED_EX *moreover)
{
    OVERLAPPED_EX *over = moreover;
    DWORD bytes = 0;
    SOCKET socket = m_readov[index] != NULL ? m_readov[index]->socket : NULL;

    if (!over) {
        ScopedLock lock(&m_lock);

        if (!msg) {
            LOG(WARNING) << "Empty send! Ignoring!";
            return FALSE;
        } else if (m_readov[index] != NULL) {
            LOG(DEBUG) << ++created << "\t:\t" << deleted << "\t\t\t\r";
            over = new OVERLAPPED_EX(this, m_readov[index]->socket, index, msg);
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    if (WSASend(socket, &(over->wsabuf), 1, &bytes, 0, (LPWSAOVERLAPPED)over, &CCommunicationServer::WorkerSendRoutine) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        bytes = bytes = WSAGetLastError();

        if (bytes != WSA_IO_PENDING) {
            LOG(ERROR) << std::endl << "WSASend() failed w/err " << bytes;
            shutdown(socket, SD_BOTH);
            LOG(DEBUG) << created << "\t:\t" << ++deleted << "\t\t\t\r";
            delete over;
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

And here are Completion routines:

```
void CALLBACK CCommunicationServer::WorkerReadRoutine(DWORD Error, DWORD BytesTransferred, LPWSAOVERLAPPED Overlapped, DWORD InFlags)
{
    OVERLAPPED_EX *over = (OVERLAPPED_EX*)Overlapped;

    if (Error)
        return;

    if (BytesTransferred > 0) {
        over->server->GetRequest(over);
    }

    over->server->ManageReadMessage(over->index);
}

void CALLBACK CCommunicationServer::WorkerSendRoutine(DWORD Error, DWORD BytesTransferred, LPWSAOVERLAPPED Overlapped, DWORD InFlags)
{
    OVERLAPPED_EX *over = (OVERLAPPED_EX*)Overlapped;

    if (Error || over->wsabuf.len == BytesTransferred) {
        LOG(DEBUG) << over->server->created << "\t:\t" << ++over->server->deleted << "\t\t\t\r";
        delete over;
    } else {
        over->wsabuf.buf += BytesTransferred;
        over->wsabuf.len -= BytesTransferred;
        over->server->ManageSendMessage(over->index, NULL, over);
    }
}
```

The variables `created` and `deleted` shows how many `OVERLAPPED_EX` structures were created and then released to avoid memory leakage.

Comment: You should zero your `OVERLAPPED` structure before you use it in the overlapped I/O. In particular `hEvent` must be set to `NULL`, otherwise the system interprets it a a notification mechanism, and may ignore your completion routine. Are you sure you zero-initialize it?

Comment: are all send/recv from the same thread which wait in alertable mode ?

Comment: @valdo yes I set `hEvent=NULL;` in costructor 
@RbMm I create a thread and do a `result = (UCHAR)WSAWaitForMultipleEvents((DWORD)m_total, m_events, FALSE, WSA_INFINITE, TRUE);` there. So `WSASend` has enough time to call a completion routine. Actually it calls it once every time after app perform `WSARead`
`

Comment: If that could help complete WS2013 solution is here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7BCrJnkzKPvY244Z2FUaldWdDA

Comment: @htonus: Are you issuing `WSASend/WSARecv` in the same thread that waits in alertable state? Because the completion routing would be called in the same thread, hence this thread must call alertable wait.

Comment: @htonus - i ask not about this. i ask from which thread you can call `WSASend`. are this well known or arbitrary thread (which is error in your case)